# Setting a threshold on code coverage on Angular 4 project using cli 1.7.1 not failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, jenkins, angular-cli

```
coverageIstanbulReporter: {
    reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary' ],
    fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
    thresholds: {
        statements: 80,
        lines: 80,
        branches: 80,
        functions: 80
    }
},
angularCli: {
    environment: 'dev'
},
reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
    ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
    : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
```

here is the output

Coverage summary

- Statements   : 73.11% ( 2042/2793 ) Branches     : 51.93% ( 444/855 )
  Functions    : 65.52% ( 420/641 ) Lines        : 71.76% ( 1751/2440 )

I set the code coverage ABOVE what it really is and not sure why it is not failing?

I want it to fail if it gets below a certain percentage so when it builds on Jenkins it will fail so developers are forced to apply unit tests to their code

Comment: What gave you the impression that just setting these thresholds was going to fail something when you run the tests? If you want something to fail with Jenkins, then set up something in Jenkins to do that.

Comment: @R.Richards.  If you could set something up on Jenkins to check if the statements for example is greater than 80, then wouldn't it be from the build console terminal?  It would have to run a command to check.  My point is that whatever I do on Jenkins I should also be able to do locally.  When I do my angularJS app that uses "gulp test" it will fail if the code coverage is less than specifed.  It will fail locally BEFORE you push the code.  Isn't this the purpose ?  To prevent having a build failure?